# Десериализация даты в виде строки в формате unix timestamp на C++

Tags: c++, файлы, csv, fstream, unixtimestamp

Имеется некая таблица MS Excel(в формате CSV), которая содержит n-ое количество строк, содержащих некоторые данные, разделенные ";". Один из видов данных - время в формате unix timestamp. Какой есть эффективный способ считывания и преобразования данных из файла, дальнейшей записи в структуру на С++?

Comment: Пример данных в студию.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, одна из строк таблицы(1;Ivan;777;1850040995;1) : 1 число в скобках - id, 2 - имя, 3 - просто рандомное число, 4 - та самая дата, которую нужно считать, 5 - булевское число. Такую строку надо считать из таблицы в структуры по полям(в структуре есть поле id, имя и т.д.).

Comment: определённости ради добавь определение структуры и пример данных к вопросу... если кратко, то время можно банально читать в `time_t`, хотя строго говоря это не гарантируется, данный тип почти всегда отсчитывает время от unix-эпохи... собственно в таком случае просто используй `scanf` или для плюсовых потоков `operator>>`...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, можете привести минимальный пример кода для считывания данных? Есть такая структура и функция для считывания:   `                 
struct Record
{
 uint64_t id;

 string partner;

 uint32_t number;

 // поле для даты

 bool status;
};                                                                                                                                               
void ReadFile()
{
 fstream file("Test.cvs");

 if (!(file.is_open()))
 {
  cout << "Error! Something wrong with file opening!" << endl;

  return;
 }
 else
 {
  
 }
}     `

Comment: На будущее: добавляй код/всё что необходимо для ответа на вопрос прямо в его текст — под ним есть серая кнопочка `править`.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, постарался реализовать как вы предложили, но что-то пошло не так, гляньте пожалуйста. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fbc79b22e05b046d

Comment: `scanf("%d;%[^;];%d;%lld;%d", &id, name, &number, &timestamp, &b)`  -- при вводе без ошибок вернет 5, позволяет вводить имена с пробелами внутри

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*file.in*:

```
1;Ivan;777;1850040995;1
```

Чтение будет выглядеть примерно следующим образом:

```
struct Record {
    uint64_t id;
    string partner;
    time_t number; // поле для даты
    bool status;
}; 

//...

std::ifstream fin{"file.in"};
struct Record rec;
char dummy;

fin >> rec.id >> std::ws >> dummy;
if (dummy!=';') {
  fin.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
}

std::getline (fin, rec.partner, ';');
fin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<long>::digits10, ';');
fin >> rec.number >> std::ws >> dummy;
if (dummy!=';') {
  fin.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
}

fin >> rec.status;

if (fin.fail()) {
  std::cerr << "Malformed input" << std::endl;
}
```

Для даты стоит использовать тип предназначенный для этого — `time_t`. Это арифметический целочисленный тип; строго говоря, не гарантируется, что этот он представляет собой именно unix-timestamp, но по факту это почти на всех системах так. Отдельно, [не стоит](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_2038_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0) использовать 32-х битные типы для хранения подобных.

---

Парсинг с помощью плюсовых потоков — всё же реализован относительно криво, для относительно элегантного варианта ожидания/верификации конкретных символов в потоке можно воспользоваться [ответом отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23304177/c-alternative-for-parsing-input-with-sscanf#answer-23305012).

Comment: [std::chrono](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono)?

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, не поможете с исправлением? пока не могу сориентироваться в плане чтения даты. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fbc79b22e05b046d

Comment: @Koka_LV, просто попробуйте мой ответ, там все работает

Comment: @Koka_LV, да, глупость написал... забыл, что оно так не работает... сейчас поправлю...

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, просто в вашем примере вы явно заполняете data.txt. А у меня имеется таблица формата .csv, где есть несколько полей.

Comment: @Koka_LV, дык это и есть csv. Или вас расширение смущает? Могу переименовать в data.csv, если хотите.

Comment: @Koka_LV, да, кстати, ввод-вывод неплохо будет обернуть в функции, как у *yrHeTaTeJlb*... единственное что там возможны проблемы с избыточными пробелами перед разделителем...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, я неправильно донес свое мысль,поэтому произошла путаница у меня в голове... если у нас есть таблица MS Excel формата .csv, содержащая несколько строк. Мне нужно считать эти строки поочередно и вывести информацию, которая содержится в них. Планировал я это сделать путем записи каждой строчки как объекта в вектор. Надеюсь, сейчас я правильно донес. Если есть возможность - что здесь нужно поменять,чтобы выполнялось вышесказанное: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7018fd8a637aab91

Comment: @Fat-Zer, а ведь и правда. `in.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ';')` решает проблему с лишними символами

Comment: @Koka_LV, вы не поверите, но это именно то, что происходит в моем примере. За исключением того, что у меня нет _таблицы MS Excel формата .csv_, и поэтом создавать ее приходится самостоятельно

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, но создаёт проблему, если там что-то непотребное вместо пробелов ;)... поэтому лучше воспользоваться манипулятором, как на enSO написано, или колхозный вариант с dummy-символом — это позволяет достаточно строго и гибко верифицировать ввод...

Comment: @Koka_LV, ну, дык, понятно, что в онлайн-компиляторе работать не будет — там такого файла нет... у себя тоже проверь, что он корректно открывается... в остальном добавь цикл чтения и всё будет работать...

Comment: @Koka_LV, не догоняете. Откуда в онлайн компиляторе возьмется `Test.csv`? Локально отлаживайте. И строки у вас в файле не `1;Ivan;777;1850040995;1`, a `"1;Ivan;777;1850040995;1"`. Возможно стоит эти кавычки убрать из файла, или отбросить при чтении, тут уже смотрите сами что вам удобнее

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, кончено я сейчас это дело пытаюсь настроить не в онлайн компиляторе, а в MSVS 2017, в любом случае спасибо, буду пробовать.

Answer (score 1):

Допустим у вас есть следующая структура

```
struct Line{
    using Clock = std::chrono::system_clock;
    using TimePoint = Clock::time_point;

    int id = 0;
    std::string name;
    int number = 0;
    TimePoint time;
    bool flag = false;
};
```

Есть разные способы заполнить ее значениями из файла, но я предпочитаю перегрузку `operator>>` и за компанию `operator>>`.

```
struct Line{
//..

friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &in, Line &line)
{
    in >> line.id;
    in.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ';');

    std::getline(in, line.name, ';');

    in >> line.number;
    in.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ';');

    std::time_t time = 0;
    in >> time;
    line.time = Line::Clock::from_time_t(time);
    in.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ';');

    in >> line.flag;

    return in;
}
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Line &line)
    {
        out << line.id                           << ';'
            << line.name                         << ';'
            << line.number                       << ';'
            << Line::Clock::to_time_t(line.time) << ';'
            << line.flag                         << ';';

        return out;
    }
};
```

`in.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ';');` нужен для того, чтобы пропустить непрочитанные символы до `;` включительно. timestamp чиатется в [`std::time_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time_t), и конвертируется в [`std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock)(если вдруг класс `system_clock` не нравится, можете выбрать [другой](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono)).

---

[Проверяем](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b177e31743b9154)

```
int main()
{
    {
        //Заполняем файл данными для теста
        std::ofstream data{"data.txt"};
        data << " 1 ; Ivan   ;  777  ; 1850040995  ; 1\n"
                "2;Alex;31337;1850045946;0\n"
                "3;Sam;13;1850047631;1\n"
                "4;Dean;666;1850047513;0\n";
    }

    //Читаем только что созданный файл
    std::ifstream data{"data.txt"};
    std::vector<Line> lines(std::istream_iterator<Line>(data), {});

    //Выводим на экран
    std::copy(lines.begin(), lines.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Line>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще один вариант чтения подобных форматов, это использовать сишную (С++ ее тоже приемлет) функцию [fscanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf).

Для чтения вашей структуры:

```
struct recd {
  uint64_t  id;
  string    name;
  int       number;
  time_t    ts;
  bool      b;
};
```

с учетом замечания в комментариях, что данные во всех строках заключены в кавычки (`"`), получаем вот такую функцию:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define NAME_LEN 4096

int
get_csv_record (struct recd *p, FILE *f)
{
  char name[NAME_LEN];
  int  b,
       r = fscanf(f, "\" %" SCNu64 " ;%[^;]; %d ; %" SCNiFAST32 " ; %d \"\n",
                 &p->id, name, &p->number, &p->ts, &b);
  if (r > 0) {
    p->b = (b != 0);
    p->name = name;
  }

  return r;
}
```

Форматы ввода `uin64_t` -- `SCNu64` и `time_t` -- `SCNiFAST32` (32 разряда в 32-бит и 64 в 64-бит системах)  определены в `<inttypes.h>`. Это макросы, значения которых зависят от разрядности системы.

На мой взгляд все получилось весьма компактно. Еще бы, ведь `scanf()` для подобных вещей и задумывалась. Если бы структура содержала только базовые типы, все вообще свелось бы к одной строке с `return fscanf(...);` -)

Для теста делаем  программку:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct recd {
  uint64_t  id;
  string    name;
  int       number;
  time_t    ts;
  bool      b;
};

int
get_csv_record (struct recd *p, FILE *f);

int main ()
{
  struct recd r;

  while (get_csv_record(&r, stdin) == 5)
    cout << r.id << "  "
     << '"' << r.name << '"' << "  "
     << r.number << "  "
     << r.ts << "  "
     << (r.b ? "true" : "false")
     << '\n';
}
```

и вот такой файл (даже с пустыми строками):

```
avp@avp-xubu2:~/hashcode$ cat t
"  221 ;hshhs sj;1;1234567899876;17"
"222;ww "hs'hhs" . sj;2; 12345;1"

"223;wwh  sh hs sj;3; 987456; 1   "  


"   224  ;ww hshhs sj; 4; 78654 ;   0"


avp@avp-xubu2:~/hashcode$
```

Транслируем и печатаем:

```
avp@avp-xubu2:~/hashcode$ g++ tt2.cpp tt3.cpp && ./a.out <t
221  "hshhs sj"  1  1234567899876  true
222  "ww "hs'hhs" . sj"  2  12345  true
223  "wwh  sh hs sj"  3  987456  true
224  "ww hshhs sj"  4  78654  false
avp@avp-xubu2:~/hashcode$
```